# How to add and view child objects in Firebase (Android)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a similar issue in which I have my files as follow in which I want to be able to view all child items and add new child items.

I understand that you will have to modify the code in the Java file, but I am having trouble understanding how to manipulate my own code and I tried to follow the confusing documentation provided by Firebase.

Below is the structure of my database followed by my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The only problem I have now is how to properly populate the listview with the values of the following structure of my database.

It is as follows: Messages --> Message --> value of which has concatenated string

I hope this isn't confusing

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
     package com.example.sean.messengerappsean;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.Query;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.collection.ArraySortedMap;
import com.firebase.client.realtime.util.StringListReader;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //TextView mTextFieldCondition;
    EditText editUsername, editValue;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    Button btnSend;
    Firebase mRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //mTextFieldCondition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCondition);
        editUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        editValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editValue);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        mRef = new Firebase("https://androidmessagetest.firebaseio.com/"); //CAN USE THE CODE HERE TO PUBLISH TO SPECIFIC LOCATION OR DB
        //TRYING TO SET LISTVIEW
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        final ArrayList<String> msgsArray = new ArrayList<String>(); //USE THIS FOR POPULATING THE VIEW






        final ValueEventListener valueEventListener = mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                //----------CONDITION FOR LISTING DATA----------------
                //MIGHT NEED TO PUT VALUES INTO ARRAY AND READ THEM OUT IN ORDER OF PUBLISH
                //String text = dataSnapshot.child("Message").child("Enter Username3").getValue(String.class);
                //mTextFieldCondition.setText(text);

                //POPULATE LISTVIEW
                for (DataSnapshot Datasnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   msgsArray.add(Datasnapshot.child("Messages").child("Message").getKey());

                }

                ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, msgsArray);
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);




            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //NEED TO DYNAMICALLY CHANGE VALUE TO USERNAME: MESSAGE
                String textoutput = String.valueOf(editUsername.getText());
                String MessageText = String.valueOf(editValue.getText());

                //FIXED MESSAGE ADD CHILD AND HOW TO ADD VALUE TO MESSAGE
                //TRY TO USE BELOW CODE FOR MESSAGES LATER ON

                mRef.child("Messages").child("Message").push().setValue(textoutput + ": " + MessageText);



            }
        });

        //ADD FUNCTION TO LOOK FOR DATA


    }
}
```

Here is my XML file activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sean.messengerappsean.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCondition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/mTextFieldCondition"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
            android:text="Condition" />-->

        //ENTER IN CODE BELOW FOR VIEWING OUTPUT OF DATA
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editValue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="Enter Message Here" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editUsername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:text="Enter Username" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if you want to show a list, I recommend you use a RecyclerView. This will definitely help you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated it, but am unable to learn how to do the list view for my data. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Use a recyclerview. It's somehow a bit complicated to implement but performance wise, it will make a huge difference. To use a recyclerview you need to add an adapter and a viewholder.

Comment: @Michele La Ferla: Thank you for the response. I will look into that.

Comment: As of now I can get the view of only message which is displayed on a data change. I had to use the following code to get it, but I would like to display the values. How might I be able to manipulate the code in my project?

Comment: @MicheleLaFerla: I was wondering how I can manipulate the updated list view to not display Message, but the values within the child named Messsage?

Answer (score 2):

These imports are for classes in the legacy SDK:

```
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.Query;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
```

These are for the new SDK:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
```

You cannot mix the two SDKs.  You should use the new SDK only.  Remove this statement from your build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.x.x'
```

and make the approriate code changes to use the new SDK.  Documentation and examples are [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/).  There is also an [Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).

Comment: Why can't the two SDKs be mixed? Might be useful to share context as many may land here looking to do just that.

Comment: @Kato:  Can they be mixed?  I haven't actually tested it.  My answer was based on previous posts where (as I recall) there were problems.  I'll have to review.

Comment: I'm also unsure on Android, but it would be great to have that context here if we can find out : )

Comment: I have updated my android java file which is now able to post, but I am having trouble with retrieving the data.

Comment: @qbix: Yes for some reason I have found I can mix them and they are completely fine as of my knowledge.

Comment: Add a log statement to `onCancelled()` to see why the listener is failing.  What is `firebaseError.getMessage()`?